# Is there a way to only scrape data visible on the webpage using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the filtered reviews from TripAdvisor using Selenium on Python. Example webpage here: https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g294264-d4009739-Reviews-S_E_A_Aquarium-Sentosa_Island.html

I was able to insert the keyword that I am interested in to the webpage by using Selenium using:

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='text']")
inputElement.send_keys("hours")
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

[Results after filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq8Lj.png)

The webdriver shows the filtered results. However, when I start scraping the reviews. I am getting the reviews before filtering. Here's my code to get the review IDs that are relevant:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[data-reviewid]")

# get attribute
for ele in elements:
    try:
        if ele.get_attribute("data-reviewid"):
            print (ele.get_attribute("data-reviewid"))
    except:
        pass
```

Can anyone please help to solve this problem? I tried using is_displayed but it still does not work. Thank you so much

Comment: You seem to grab 5 elements loop them and print their attribute.

Comment: Yes, for now I am just printing the review ids of the elements. But, the review IDs I got are the non-filtered one. Do you know how to just print those that are filtered? (i.e. with 'hours' only)

Comment: and //span[contains(text(), "hours")] something like that.